# parser for ics files in .net

Tags: c#, calendar, icalendar

I'm trying to figure out the best way take a ics file and convert it into a format I can put into a database. Can anyone recommend how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The commercial .NET library Aspose.iCal does the job

http://www.aspose.com/community/blogs/salman.sarfraz/archive/2008/11/21/where-is-aspose-icalendar.aspx (used to be http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.network-for-.net/default.aspx)

Or this open source parser (didn't try it)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/icalparser/

And this online iCal validator comes in handy

http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/

Regards,
tamberg

Answer (score 9):

There's an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/iCalendar1.aspx) of parsing iCalendar files. It is based on the [DDay.iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/) library.

Comment: This seems to be the most promising one

Comment: My experience is that the DDay.iCal library won't save you time, it will cost you much time to work around several annoying bugs. I didn't test the other libraries, but I would certainly NOT recomment the DDay.iCal library to anyone.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that DDay.iCal is unfortunately not AOT (Ahead of Time) compilation-safe, meaning that if you are for example developing for IOS with Unity, DDay.iCal would require special patching.

Comment: Link no longer works

Answer (score 1):

I used https://github.com/der-Daniel/ical.NET which is also available on Nuget.