# Toolset to parse iCalendar file in C

Tags: c, regex

I need to parse an ics file in C and will be doing it line by line. Each line can vary a lot by their format but generally holds a standard.

Here are some rules I have noticed:

- There is a **property name**
- Optional parameters which each start with a semicolon

  - Can have CSV too
  - Can be double quoted values, in which case things like commas, semi colons, and colons would need to be ignored within this
- Colon
- Property value

Here is an example ics component that would need to be parsed out:

```
UID:uid1@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john.doe@example.com
CATEGORIES:Project Report, XYZ, Weekly Meeting
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T035959Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
```

You'll notice in things like the `MAILTO` there is a following `:`. Only the first colon would be parsed, and the rest after that colon is the property value.

Using something like [strtok()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) seems to basic to be adequate for this problem.

Should something like regular expression be used to solve this problem? Looking into it, I see an example of a regex solution being done in C# on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11038866/1044984).

Comment: No, no need for regular expression. But `strtok()` is not so good for this kind of problem. Better use `strchr()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
    FILE *ics;
    char line[100];

    ics = fopen("example.ics", "r");
    if (ics == NULL)
        return -1;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), ics) != NULL)
    {
        char *separator;
        char *key;
        char *tail;
        char *value;

        if ((tail = strchr(line, '\n')) != NULL)
            *tail = '\0'; // Remove the trailing '\n'
        separator = strpbrk(line, ":;");
        if (separator == NULL)
            continue;
        *separator = '\0';

        key = line; // Maybe you want to strip surrounding white spaces
        value = separator + 1; // Maybe you want to strip surrounding white spaces

        fprintf(stdout, "%s --> %s\n", key, value);
    }
    fclose(ics);

    return 0;
}
```

Using a regular expression for this is like killing a fly with a bazooka.

Comment: Okay this looks like a good solution but what about the less basic lines like the ORGANIZER line you see in my example that contain extra data that also need to be parsed out.

Comment: Hey, do you maybe want to take a look at my new question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024861/parsing-an-icalendar-file-in-c . It explains and shows more how this parsing may need to be more complex. Would you still just use strchr in the more complex cases?

Comment: @Fogest use `strpbrk()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that looks useful. How would you suggest using this function, it looks almost the same as strchr?

Comment: @Fogest Exactly the same, just using 2 delimiters instead of 1.

Comment: Which two delimiters are you referring to? Because I have colons, semi colons, and within values, commas to account for. Along with problems like there could be multiple semi-colons which are used for having x many optional parameters. But versus colons where only the first one is the one we care about, and then the rest can be treated like a value. These kinds of quirks are what is really stumping me. Minus the quirks and yes this all seems pretty easy, but with those I am finding it complex.

Comment: @Fogest: I replaced `strchr()` with `strpbrk()` where appropriate, test it and tell me whether or not it is what you want. The other answer is too complicated and unecessarily so. Also, you should parse the value separately so don't worry for whatever is after the first importante delimiter, the one between the property name and it's value. And this code would automatically skip empty lines. It would not check for the integrity of the file though.

Comment: The other answer is covering the other bases. This code if I am understanding it correctly will just split when it finds a colon or semi colon once and that is all. There can be multiple semi colons that need to be handled in one line, but this code wouldn't account for any of that?

Comment: I told you to handle the value in a different parser. Doing it all in a single function is good now, but it will be a headache in the future.

Comment: How should I handle the data passed to the function? Because I'll need to parse out each optional parameter and not get thrown off by semi colons in quotes. Like in this sentence for example: `ORGANIZER;CN=Obi-Wan Kenobi;SENT-BY="mailto:obiwan@padawan.com":mailto:laowaion@padawan.com`

Comment: @Fogest Passed to which function?

Comment: Well this is what your function would end up with: `ORGANIZER --> CN=Obi-Wan Kenobi;SENT-BY="mailto:obiwan@padawan.com":mailto:laowaion@padawan.com` Are you suggesting I pass that second part there to another function to further parse it?

Comment: Exactly, create a structure to hold the values. But parse the values separated from the names. Then if you had an structure say `Property` you could `property.name = strdup(key);` and `property.value = isc_parse_value(value);`. It's a lot cleaner than the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

```c
// disclaimer : no support 
// code provided as a  example of minimal things one can do.

#include <malloc.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct value { 
   struct value *next; 
   char *val; 
};
struct property { 
   struct property *next; 
   char *prop; 
};
struct parameter { 
   struct property *props; 
   struct value *vals; 
   struct parameter *next; 
   char *name; 
};
enum PARSE_STATE { PARAMETER, PROPERTY, VALUE };

//format for lines is...
//   PARAMETER[;PARAM_PROPERTY..]:VALUE[,VALUE2..]\n

struct parameter *parse( char *input )
{
    size_t start, end;
    char *buf;
    enum PARSE_STATE state;
    struct parameter *root = NULL;
    struct parameter *new_parameter;
    struct property *new_property;
    struct value *new_value;
    char in_quote = 0;
    start = end = 0;
    state = PARAMETER;
    while( input[end] )
    {
        switch( state ) 
        { 
        case PARAMETER : 
            if( input[end] == ';' || input[end] == ':' ) {
               new_parameter = malloc( sizeof( struct parameter ) );
               new_parameter->next = root;
               new_parameter->name = malloc( end - start + 1 );
               strncpy( new_parameter->name, input + start, end - start );
               new_parameter->name[end-start] = 0;
               new_parameter->props = new_parameter->vals = NULL;
               root = new_parameter;
               start = end + 1;
               if( input[end] == ';' )
                  state = PROPERTY;
               else 
                  state = VALUE;
             }
             break;
        case PROPERTY :
             if( input[end] == '"' ) {
                if( !in_quote ) 
                   in_quote = input[start];
                else if( input[start] == in_quote ) 
                   in_quote = 0;
                break;
             }
             if( in_quote ) break;
             if( input[end] == ';' || input[end] == ':' ) {
                new_property = malloc( sizeof( struct property ) );
                new_property->prop = malloc( end - start + 1 );
                strncpy( new_property->prop, input + start, end - start );
                new_property->prop[end-start] = 0;
                new_property->next = root->props;
                root->props = new_property;
                if( input[end] == ':' ) 
                   state = VALUE;
                start = end + 1;
                break;
             }
             break;   
        case VALUE : 
             if( input[end] == '\n' || input[end] == ',' ) {
                new_value = malloc( sizeof( struct value ) );
                new_value->val = malloc( end - start + 1 );
                strncpy( new_value->val, input + start, end - start );
                new_value->val[end-start] = 0;
                new_value->next = root->vals;
                root->vals = new_value;
                if( input[end] == '\n' ) 
                    state = PARAMETER;
                start = end + 1;
             }
             break;
        }
        end++;
    }
    if( end != start )
       fprintf( stderr, "missing newline at end of input\n" );
    return root;
}


void DumpResult( struct parameter *root )
{
   struct property *prop;
   struct value *val;
   for( ; root; root = root->next ) {
         printf( "%s ", root->name );
         for( prop = root->props; prop; prop = prop->next ) 
              printf( "; %s ", prop->prop );
         for( val = root->vals; val; val = val->next ) {
            if( val == root->vals ) 
               printf( " : %s ", val->val );
            else 
               printf( ", %s ", val->val );
         }
         printf( "\n" );
   }
}
```

And... using the above code.
The values do all get reversed....

```
void main( void )
{
    char *string = "UID:uid1@example.com\n"
                           "DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z\n"
                           "ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe;SENT-BY=\"mailto:smith@example.com\":mailto:john.doe@example.com\n"
                           "CATEGORIES:Project Report, XYZ, Weekly Meeting\n"
                           "DTSTART:19970714T170000Z\n"
                           "DTEND:19970715T035959Z\n"
                           "SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party\n";
    struct parameter *thing = parse( string );
    DumpResult( thing );
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, terrible coding style. It would take more time than needed to understand the code. Consider avoiding single line `if` statements and a better use of white space to improve the coding style. Also, consider using `int main(void)`, do you know the difference?

Comment: void main() would have been a better suggestion :)  Either way no arguments are used...Do you know?   Expanded the few If statements; sorry bad habits from playing with Go .

Comment: `void main()` is not a valid signature.